# PDFAnnotationMarkup.setQuadrilateralPoints in Swift

Tags: swift, pdf

I'm try to use the setQuadrilateralPoints member function of PDFAnnotationMarkup in Swift to highlight some pdf text. I cannot figure out how to pass an array of points to define the boundaries and was hoping someone might be able to help.

Comment: this ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

this ended up working for me:

```
                    let pdfAnnotationMarkup = PDFAnnotationMarkup()

                    let p1: NSValue = NSValue(point: CGPointMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y))
                    let p2: NSValue = NSValue(point: CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height))
                    let p3: NSValue = NSValue(point: CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height))
                    let p4: NSValue = NSValue(point: CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width, rect.origin.y))


                    pdfAnnotationMarkup.setQuadrilateralPoints([p2,p3,p1,p4])
```